# Django tutorial (using the guide on Heroku), “Please supply the ENGINE value” (yes, I've read other threads)

Tags: python, django, web-applications, heroku

I've read a lot of similar questions, and I've spent a lot of time trying to work this out myself, but I'm still stuck. Here's my situation:

I'm going through the Django guide on Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django). I originally started in windows, but after having all sorts of problems I decided it would be a lot easier to switch to linux. I wiped my hard drive and installed Ubuntu 12.10 and Win 7 side by side to dual boot. Everything has been installed with pip (again, following the Heroku guide). I'm using PostgreSQL since it is (supposedly) well-integrated with Heroku. Before I get into what I've tried, here is the error (it's from near the end of the tutorial):

```
(venv)wtodom@wubuntu:~/hellodjango$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 15, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

If I try to specify the settings file with its absolute path to make sure it uses the right one I get this:

```
(venv)wtodom@wubuntu:~/hellodjango$ python manage.py syncdb --settings=/home/wtodom/hellodjango/hellodjango/settings.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/wtodom/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings '/home/wtodom/hellodjango/hellodjango/settings.py' (Is it on sys.path?): Import by filename is not supported.
```

A lot of the similar questions had people editing the wrong settings.py file. I know I edited the right one. Here's a cat of it (on gist since it's kinda long) - https://gist.github.com/wtodom/4736303. I've tried every combination I can think of for the data in there, including empty strings - no difference.

Other posts I've read have had people who had issues with the Django version they were running. Mine is a fresh install through and through, so it's not that.

Some people had issues with Django not being on the path. If I open a python shell from the projects root directory I can import things, so it's not that.

Some people didn't have values in their settings.py file, but as you can see from the gist, I do. I also tried running the command (`python manage.py syncdb`) both with and without pgadmin running and logged in.

On that note, here is a screencap of pgadmin showing that I have databases created and up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0KfC.png

Here's what I get when I \l in PostgreSQL (another gist since SO killed the formatting): https://gist.github.com/wtodom/4736359

While I'm at it, here's a \du listing: https://gist.github.com/wtodom/4736442

I made sure that my manage.py has `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "hellodjango.settings")` in it.

Everything in the Heroku tutorial worked without a hitch in Ubuntu up until I tried to sync the db locally (python manage.py syncdb). I can run the same command through heroku and it works fine (`heroku run python manage.py syncdb`).

I'm sure I'd forgotten probably something relevant that I've tried or read. I've spent about 6 hours reading and trying to get this thing going, just on this one error. I don't really know what else to try.

Also, I'm really new to databases and non-.NET web development (I've worked on projects, but never set one up), so if you know what's wrong with my setup please try to be clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: To ensure you are using the right settings file, you want to specify the module (not absolute path to file): **./manage.py syncdb --settings=hellodjango.settings**  However, I don't think that's your problem - more likely it has something to do with this line towards the bottom of settings.py: DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config().  What happens if you remove that?

Comment: @NathanJhaveri specifying the settings file like that doesn't change anything.

Removing the dj_database_url() line got the command to work, but since using the dj_databse_url module was recommended, I'm not really sure what will change now. I got a slot of warnings when i ran `foreman start`, so I'll have to research those now and see what they're about (link to the second time i tried to run it: https://gist.github.com/wtodom/4738716).I'll do some reading up on it and hopefully be able to figure it out.

Thanks for the suggestion (and if you have any more please let me know!).

Comment: So we know it has something to do with the line **DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()**.  Settings.py is just python, so you could debug it or do a **print DATABASES['default']** on line 160 and see if the DATABASE configuration matches what you are expecting.  Can you update with the actual DB configuration being used?

Comment: @NathanJhaveri Sorry for the delay. I actually decided just to start over with a different tutorial. I don't think I'm familiar enough with wevdev, Django, or databases to get much from the Heroku getting started guide, so I decided to start out on the official Django tutorial and work up from there. I also switched to MySQL. So far things are going pretty well, though database setup is still pretty confusing.

Comment: no worries, I know getting started can be daunting.  Django is a great framework and will likely make your life easier in the long run, so stick with it.

Answer (score 8):

Heroku and your local machine usually need different database settings.  A common way to handle that is to first list your local database settings in the settings.py file, then do a check to see if you're code is currently running on Heroku, and if so, override your database settings with what Heroku needs. That allows a single settings.py file to work in both environments.

Heroku creates an environment variable called DATABASE_URL containing the database URL string.  A common way to check whether your code is running on Heroku is to check for that environment variable.  Then, if it exists, use the dj_database_url module, which knows how to parse that string into the dictionary that Django needs for its configuration.

The only thing incorrect in your code is that you didn't check for the environment variable first before calling dj_database_url.config().  This means that dj_database_url, which normally should only run within Heroku, was running on your local machine too. Since your local machine almost certainly doesn't have the DATABASE_URL environment variable set, dj_database_url returned an empty dictionary. So, your code is overwriting your local database configuration with an empty dictionary when it's not run on Heroku. Django looks in that dictionary for the information it needs, can't find it, and raises an error.

To fix the problem, add a check for DATABASE_URL before using dj_database_url.

Change this part at the end of settings.py:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

To this:

```
if os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', None):
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, but unfortunately I've long since moved on from the project. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sure. I saw the post was old, but in case you or any one else ran into this problem again, it doesn't hurt to have the answer available.

Comment: Definitely. I would accept the answer to make it more obvious for people searching, but it seems a little off to do it when I haven't actually checked that it worked for me.


**So, for anyone looking** - This probably solves the problem, but I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: This answer is extremely helpful. Small note: this conditional might need to be applied to a few of the other statements in the block heroku gives to add to settings.py. You need to carefully audit what does and doesn't make sense with the rest of your settings, but it can work and this is a key piece.